# C: incompatible types in assignment

Tags: c

```
 typedef char Last_t[MAXL];
 typedef char Rest_t[MAXR];

 typedef struct NodeTag {
 Last_t     Last;
 Rest_t     Rest;
 struct NodeTag *Link;
 }  Node;

typedef struct {
Node *Index[26];
Node *L;
} ContactList;
```

// parameter to take in a char argument to set it to contact.Last

```
void INS( Node *cn   ) 
Node contactName;
contactName.Last= cn;
// temp->data=num;
//contactName.Rest=restName;

}
```

//cant figure out how to pass a char argument

```
 int main(void)
 {

   INS("David"); 
 }
```

Comment: contactName.Last = cn ; is sending me an error "incompatible types in assignment.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Your suggestion looks wrong to me.

Comment: @self. yes it is wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`void INS` should be passing an argument of type `char *`, not `Node`, if you want the code in your `main` to work.

To assign it to the member `Last`, you would have to use `strcpy` or something similar. This is because you can't assign a pointer to an array. More specifically, you can't assign a `char *` to `char[MAXL]`.

You could try this:

```
void INS( char * cn   ) {
    Node contactName;
    strncpy (contactName.Last, cn, MAXL);
}

int main(void){
    INS("David");
    return 0;
}
```

But, this doesn't handle errors very well. Here's a way of doing it that's more error-safe:

```
void INS (char * cn){

    Node contactName = {
        .Last[0] = 0,
        .Rest[0] = 0,
        .Link = 0
    };

    if (cn){
        strncpy (contactName.Last, cn, MAXL - 1);
        contactName.Last[MAXL - 1] = 0;
    }
}

int main (void){
    INS ("David");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: better to use strcpy() or strncpy(). No need of for loop.